# CARP Virtual IP does not ping in virtualized environment

Tags: virtualization, redundancy, smartos, carp

We have three physical machines with SmartOS on them in a LAN. Two of them, `10.40.0.30` and `10.40.0.240` are hypervisors with two pfSense-based virtualized gateways on them. These gateways have `10.40.0.1` and `10.40.0.2` addresses, respectively. There is a `10.40.0.3` virtual IP shared between the gateways.
Third SmartOS machine, `10.40.0.221`, is a storage host. The following is an ARP table from it:

```
[root@68-05-ca-1a-d2-eb ~]# arp -a -n
Net to Media Table: IPv4
Device   IP Address               Mask      Flags      Phys Addr
------ -------------------- --------------- -------- ---------------
aggr0  224.0.0.251          255.255.255.255 S        01:00:5e:00:00:fb
aggr0  10.40.0.2            255.255.255.255          f2:b4:a3:21:de:9f
aggr0  10.40.0.3            255.255.255.255          00:00:5e:00:01:02
aggr0  10.40.0.1            255.255.255.255          a2:b1:25:07:ea:97
aggr0  10.40.0.15           255.255.255.255          20:6a:8a:0e:a5:6e
aggr0  10.40.0.30           255.255.255.255          02:08:20:ee:5b:8b
aggr0  10.40.0.240          255.255.255.255          02:08:20:3e:aa:9e
aggr0  224.0.0.22           255.255.255.255 S        01:00:5e:00:00:16
aggr0  10.40.0.221          255.255.255.255 SPLA     68:05:ca:1a:d2:eb
[root@68-05-ca-1a-d2-eb ~]#
```

As you can see, the ARP table has an entry for the shared virtual IP. The problem is that neither we can ping the shared IP from the storage host nor we see incoming ICMP packets on pfSense virtual machines.

We guess the problem is related to virtualization somehow. We removed all restrictions from a virtualized network card:

```
root@a0-36-9f-17-e3-fe ~ dladm show-linkprop net1 -z d783afd7-f8e0-48bf-bc9d-b41939e7b8f8            
LINK         PROPERTY        PERM VALUE          DEFAULT        POSSIBLE
net1         autopush        rw   --             --             -- 
net1         zone            rw   d783afd7-f8e0-48bf-bc9d-b41939e7b8f8 -- -- 
net1         state           r-   unknown        up             up,down 
net1         mtu             rw   1500           1500           1500 
net1         secondary-macs  rw   --             --             -- 
net1         maxbw           rw   --             --             -- 
net1         cpus            rw   --             --             -- 
net1         cpus-effective  r-   1-2            --             -- 
net1         pool            rw   --             --             -- 
net1         pool-effective  r-   --             --             -- 
net1         priority        rw   high           high           low,medium,high 
net1         tagmode         rw   vlanonly       vlanonly       normal,vlanonly 
net1         protection      rw   --             --             mac-nospoof,
                                                                restricted,
                                                                ip-nospoof,
                                                                dhcp-nospoof 
net1         promisc-filtered rw  off            on             off,on 
net1         allowed-ips     rw   --             --             -- 
net1         allowed-dhcp-cids rw --             --             -- 
net1         rxrings         rw   --             --             -- 
net1         rxrings-effective r- --             --             -- 
net1         txrings         rw   --             --             -- 
net1         txrings-effective r- --             --             -- 
net1         txrings-available r- 0              --             -- 
net1         rxrings-available r- 0              --             -- 
net1         rxhwclnt-available r- 0             --             -- 
net1         txhwclnt-available r- 0             --             -- 
root@a0-36-9f-17-e3-fe ~
```

but it did not start to work.

What else can we try?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must configure the two gateways machines where UCARP is running, adding these attributes to the network configuration:

```
  "allow_ip_spoofing": true,
  "allow_mac_spoofing": true
```

To do that you can create a file, named it for example updatenic.json

```
{
   "update_nics": [
      {
         "mac": "e2:31:fc:70:df:1c",
         "allow_ip_spoofing": true,
         "allow_mac_spoofing": true
      }
   ]
}
```

then issue the command

```
vmadm update UUID < updatenic.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enable interface virtual promisc mode in virtualbox.